# Why a language with equality in first order predicate logic has only infinite models?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I need to prove that there is no set of wff Σ of the language with equality (i.e. the language the only symbol of which is that of equality and the interpretations of this language are sets) such that:

```
A is a model of Σ iff A is a finite set
```

I have been hinted that I need to use the theorem of compactness, but I can not figure it out... Any ideas?

Comment: Either you made a mistake in the title, or you should first figure out why your title is asking for something different than the body.

Comment: I am quite sure that I haven't made any mistake.

Comment: There are plenty of first-order theories with only equality that have finite models. For example, take the theory with the lone axiom: $\forall x,y.x=y$. The only models for this theory are singleton sets.

Comment: @Zehanort The body is a standard problem. The title asks for something completely different and is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the theory $T$ that contains a formula $\phi_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\phi_n$ states there exist $n$ elements that are all unequal to each other.

It should be easy to see that any finite subset of $T$ is satisfied in a finite model. But then by compactness there exists a model of $T$. Can such a model be finite?

Now let $\Sigma$ be a theory such that $\Sigma$ is true in a model if and only if the model is finite. Then show that $\Sigma\cup T$ is consistent.

---

The title of this question is not provable, since the theory $\{\forall xy(x=y)\}$ clearly has only finite models of size 1.